# Clojure: separating comp and partial arguments

Tags: clojure

Say I have a function that needs two arguments and where the order of arguments affects the results.

Is it possible to pass the first argument into a partial or comp function and the other aside of it, like this:

```
(defn bar [arg1 arg2] (- arg1 arg2))
(def baz (partial (bar arg1)))
(def qux (comp str (bar arg1)))

(baz arg2)
(qux arg2)
```

If I want to pass arg2 into the function, could I do something like this?

```
(def baz2 (partial (bar _ arg2)))
(def qux2 (comp str (bar _ arg2)))

(baz arg1)
(qux arg1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`partial` only "fills in" arguments on the left side, so if you need to skip arguments you must use `fn`:

```
(def baz2 #(bar %1 arg2))
```

Note also that `comp` requires that all its arguments be functions, so your `qux` and `qux2` are actually nonsense. They should be:

```
(def qux (comp str baz))
(def qux2 (comp str baz2))
```

In general, Clojure core functions will place the variable most likely to change *last* to make composition with `comp` and `partial` more natural. (E.g., the collection argument is almost always last in Clojure, except for things like `into` where it makes sense to put it first.) When you design your own functions you should stick to this convention so you can compose your functions more easily.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know this convention.

Answer (score 4):

[Scheme SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) has a useful macro `cut` for slotting parameters like this.

Usage would be like so for your subtracting `bar`:

```
 ((cut bar <> 1) 2)
 ;=> 1
 ((comp str (cut - <> 1)) 2)
 ;=> "1"
```

Where the `<>` symbol represents the slot to be filled.

It is a fun exercise to implement a `cut` in Clojure yourself, but [here is one port](https://gist.github.com/ghoseb/2397263) by @Baishampayan Ghose.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I got in a repl:

```
user=> (defn bar [arg1 arg2] (- arg1 arg2))
#'user/bar
user=> (def baz (partial bar 5))
#'user/baz
user=> (def qux (comp str baz))
#'user/qux
user=> (baz 2)
3
user=> (qux 2)
"3"
```

It's the closest I could get from your first example.

For the second example, maybe a simple defn is better than a partial def:

```
user=> (defn baz2 [x] (bar x 5))
#'user/baz2
user=> (def qux2 (comp str baz2))
#'user/qux2
user=> (baz2 2)
-3
user=> (qux2 2)
"-3"
```

I'd suggest you start a repl and try it yourself, it's the second best way to discover a language that I know of (TDD being the first).

Cheers!